# dyld: Library not loaded: /Volumes/hd2/pb2/build/sb_0-18231254-1457628263.05/unixODBC-2.3.2-osx10.8-x86-64bit/lib/libodbc.2.dylib

Tags: dyld

**Does anyone know a solution for the defined problem? I am trying to install ODBC connector on Mac OS X 10.9.5, however I get the message that a particular file could not be found:**

```
$ myodbc-installer -a -d -n "MySQL ODBC 5.2 Driver" -t "Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5w.so"
```

> dyld: Library not loaded: /Volumes/hd2/pb2/build/sb_0-18231254-1457628263.05/unixODBC-2.3.2-osx10.8-x86-64bit/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
>     Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/myodbc-installer
>     Reason: image not found

**I have used otool to trace the unfound file:**

```
$ otool -L myodbc-installer
```

> myodbc-installer:
>
> /Volumes/hd2/pb2/build/sb_0-18231254-1457628263.05/unixODBC-2.3.2-osx10.8-x86-64bit/lib/libodbc.2.dylib
>   (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
>
> /Volumes/hd2/pb2/build/sb_0-18231254-1457628263.05/unixODBC-2.3.2-osx10.8-x86-64bit/lib/libodbcinst.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
>
> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version
>   1.2.5)
>
> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current
>   version 1197.1.1)
>
> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version
>   120.0.0)

`/Volumes` does exist but everything after `/hd2`does not exist on my disk. What to do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

installing unixodbc formula with brew fixeed it for me.

```
brew install unixodbc
```